# How to collect and preserve kids videos?

Tags: toddler

My son is 1.5 years old and during that time I have collected many short (5 seconds to 2 minutes) videos of him, mostly taken on my phone.

I now want to preserve the most important ones in such a way that it’s engaging to watch. A simple way would be to concatenate them in chronological order, but that probably loses quite a lot of context and does not seem very appealing.

Does anybody have recommendations on how to best combine short kids videos? Any good example or best practices?

Comment: Voting to close because while the videos are of kids in this case, this is not about parenting perse. You could ask the same question about videos of your cats, horses, clowns, … Maybe better suited on a creative forum.

Comment: @AsheraH preserving memories from their youth is something that’s unique to parenting. You can’t really do that for cats or horses.

Comment: Stefan, I’m afraid @AsheraH is correct. You don’t need parenting expertise, you need knowledge about video processing. And the problem is in no way unique to parenting, preserving and editing video material can be travel videos, competitions, pets…. The list is endless.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about a problem that’s specific to parenting. Quote from the [help] on what’s explicitly off-topic: “generic and universal questions that are […] worded "... for kids".

Comment: @StefanKögl I used a very simple and robust system for years. I store kids' videos in folders based on date, named such that their default (ASCIIbetical) sort order is also the same as chronological order. For example, videos between September 1, 2020 and December 31, 2020 are in the folder `20200901_20201231`. If your folders are all recent, this can be shortened to `209001_201231`

Comment: @StefanKögl Thank you for an interesting and useful question. I wish it stayed open, I am interested to see other answers! Perhaps try posting this question on https://photo.stackexchange.com/ or maybe try to rewrite it for a more generic computational site such as perhaps https://superuser.com/ . Good luck!

Comment: Personally, I store all my photos in google photos, which automatically keeps albums chronologically based on people that are in the photos/videos. So if I want to look at pictures/videos of my dog, I go into me "Bernie" album and it shows all pictures that I've taken of him over time.